# Rooting, bricking, and unbricking

Tags: rooting, unbricking, sony-xperia-sp

I want to root my Xperia SP C502.

I was wondering what if I bricked my device? Is there way to unbrick it? Can it be repaired? Is rooting worth its risk or I should forget the idea?

Comment: Can you boot into recovery? Does adb work? Do you have a backup or a rom to hand?

Comment: I don't know anything I was just wondering is there any procedure than I can repair bricked device

Comment: The first things are to go on xda developers for your device and search for bricked device fixes. Usually boot into recovery and flash a new ROM or restore a nandroid backup.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different cases of bricking your phone.

**1- Soft brick:** In this case, phone is not functional as it is supposed to be however it is possible to fix the phone which is usually done through custom recoveries.

**2- Hard brick:** In this case of bricking, saving phone programatically is beyond possibility and a change in hardware is necessary.

Is rooting worth it? It is pretty opinion-based. For some, rooting is what makes Android awesome. And to some, the best way to use it, is the way manufacturers wants it to be used.